# What version of MySQL Connector will work with Mono 2.10.1

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, mono, mysql-connector

I am trying to bring an ASP .NET 2.0 app up to 4.0 running under mod_mono. The 2.0 app is using the 6.3.5 version of the DLLs build against the 2.x platform and it works fine.

Here are the versions of the connector DLLs I've tried thus far:

- 6.3.5 - 2x
- 6.3.5 - 4x
- 6.5.4 - 4x

I am adding mono/4.0/machine.config like so:

```
<add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
```

The PublicKeyToken seems to be the same for all the different versions.

When I run the app though, I get this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: The assembly name is invalid.
  at System.Reflection.AssemblyName..ctor (System.String assemblyName) [0x00045] in /root/mono-2.10.1/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/AssemblyName.cs:93 
  at Mono.CSharp.ImportedAssemblyDefinition.ReadAttributes () [0x000c5] in /root/mono-2.10.1/mcs/mcs/import.cs:1522 
  at Mono.CSharp.MetadataImporter.GetAssemblyDefinition (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00028] in /root/mono-2.10.1/mcs/mcs/import.cs:821 
  at Mono.CSharp.ReflectionImporter.ImportAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace targetNamespace) [0x00000] in /root/mono-2.10.1/mcs/mcs/reflection.cs:88 
  at Mono.CSharp.DynamicLoader.LoadReferences (Mono.CSharp.ModuleContainer module) [0x0003e] in /root/mono-2.10.1/mcs/mcs/reflection.cs:587 
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00159] in /root/mono-2.10.1/mcs/mcs/driver.cs:1535 
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0003d] in /root/mono-2.10.1/mcs/mcs/driver.cs:243
```

I've read a number of posts saying this version works or that version works, I am wondering if anyone knows for sure so I don't get stuck downloading a whole bunch of dlls and jumping from one to the other when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure this out, but I did see another post indicating that they upgraded to a later version of Mono and that resolved the issue.

I upgraded to `2.10.9` and the issue seems to be fixed and the MVC2 version of the site appears to be running w/out issues.

I did have a problem with mono not finding the  v6.5.4 of the 4.0 connector so I've since reverted back to 6.3.5 and that has resolved that issue.  I am running SubSonic so it may be that SubSonic is linked against `6.3.5` and that's why 6.5.4 is not being found.